# Is it possible to drop an aggregate (Kafka streams) if a specific number of bytes is exceeded?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

My goal is to set an aggregate to `null` when a certain number of bytes (serialized json) is exceeded. Is there some way or is the retention time the only way to eventually delete aggregates?

Answer (score 2):

In general it is possible, but it might be expensive.

If your `Aggregator` returns `null`, the corresponding result row would be deleted. Thus, each time your `Aggregator` is called, you could serialize the result in your own code to check its size and return `null` if it's too big, and the new result otherwise. The additional serialization step could be expensive though.